# html dropdown with integer values?

Tags: php, html

how do i make a drop down with integer values 1-12, so that when one is chosen, that value is saved into the variable

I just want a select field in html

that is populated with 1-12

so

```
<select name="dropdown" option value= ? ? ?></select>
```

Comment: You'll need to be way more specific about what you're trying to accomplish before anyone can help you. Also, provide whatever it is you've already tried so we can build on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML:

```
<select name="myDropDown">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

In PHP:

```
// Note: Perform input sanitizing and type checking as needed here...
$myVariable = $_POST["myDropDown"];
```

Naturally, there's more scaffolding around all of this which is omitted here for brevity.  If there's more you need to know about any of that, please update the question to be more specific.  As it stands now, it's difficult to determine your experience level with the technologies in question.

Comment: Thanks is there a shortcut for typing all the values, to save up space?

Comment: @user570098: Not really. If the list is dynamic and expected to change then you can output the `option` elements in a loop with PHP code and account for changes within the logic there. But just keep in mind the trade-off between the code and the maintainability of the code. Putting in extra "cleverness" to save a little one-time typing often results in less maintainable code, so approach with caution.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using PHP, you can use a loop to generate the `<option>` elements:

```
<form method="POST">
  <select name="dropdown">
<?php
    for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++) {
        echo '    <option value="' . $x . '">' . $x . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And to read the variable:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['dropdown']) {
        // cast to integer to avoid malicious values
        $dropdown = (int)$_POST['dropdown'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using php

```
<?php

echo "<select name=\"numbers\">";
for($i = 1; $i <= 12 ; $i++){
echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>"
?>
```